# Issues with dynamic fullsize resizes of an image when the image is chosen by random via jscript

Tags: javascript

I really just want whatever image is loaded via the below jscript to be fullscreen based on whatever monitor resolution the user is looking at.

`var randomImages = new Array("Images/bodybg1.jpg", "Images/bodybg2.jpg", "Images/bodybg3.jpg", "Images/bodybg4.jpg", "Images/bodybg5.jpg");

            var randomNumber = Math.floor((randomImages.length - 0) * Math.random());
            $('#full-screen-background-image').prop('src', randomImages[randomNumber]);`

Here is the HTML
`<img alt="no image" id="full-screen-background-image" class="fssi"
                src="" />`

Is there a way to dynamically resize that image.  I tried the sample here:`http://jsbin.com/okizi5`

However, I cannot seem to get the image to resize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does setting image size to whole page work?

`<img alt="no image" id="full-screen-background-image" class="fssi" src="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"/>`

**UPDATE**

It is not possible to setup image dimension to user's monitor resolution using css from the server. But you could access current monitor dimensions by script. So add following script to your page

```
var img = document.getElementById("full-screen-background-image");
img.width = window.screen.width;
img.height = window.screen.height;
```

**UPDATE 2**

How to set dimension of background image

```
$('body').css({
     'background-image': 'url(' + randomImages[randomNumber] + ')', 
     'background-repeat': 'no-repeat', 
     'background-size':  window.screen.width + 'px ' + window.screen.height + 'px' 
});
```

Comment: That does work, I was kind of hoping to get that effect if a user manually resizes their screen

Comment: I believe it will be re-sized automatically with the browser window

Comment: it will be, but thats not what I want

Comment: ok, I've updated the answer how to use monitor resolution, please check

Comment: Andrey- if I gave the image to be an actual body background image, how do you grab that with getElemntalbyID?  $('body').css({ 'background-image': 'url(' + randomImages[randomNumber] + ')' });

Comment: ok, updated the my answer once again. Please mark as answer if you think this is what you finally want ;)

Comment: Andrey- thanks for all the help, but with your code in the update2 it will not show a background image, however with just $('body').css({ 'background-image': 'url(' + randomImages[randomNumber] + ')' }); an image will appear

Comment: Andrey thanks for all the help what if I when the person drags the window it didnt resize the image? Using the image not using it as a background?

Comment: obviously it doesn't, script sets size to maximum possible size (monitor dimensions). If you set background-size to 100% if will follow to page dimensions